# Laravel request session get return Boolean not value

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have created the middle-ware that forced the route path contained on local value
and it works great but when I tried to read locale session value it return `true` as a `Boolean` ! not value of session as en

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class Local
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {    
        if($request->method() == 'GET'){
            //get local from param
            $locale = $request->segment(1);

            //if not exist i get it from app and redirect to /local
            if(!$locale || !in_array($locale, config('app.locales')))
            {
                dd($request->session()->get('locale'));
                $locale = $request->session()->get('locale') || app()->getLocale();
                $request->session()->put('locale',$locale);

                return redirect('/'.$locale.$request->getRequestUri());
            }
            //else if exist I set the local and set the session

           else
            {
                $request->session()->put('locale',$locale);
            }

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you `dd($locale)` before put in session() and see what you get?

Comment: en I have printed the $request->session() and it gives to me array with locale as en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to use the null coalescing operator (??).

```php
$locale = $request->session()->get('locale') ?? app()->getLocale();
```

Right now it's assigning a condition to your **$locale** variable.